# Enabling attachments with DataFormWebPart on a Blog template

Tags: blog, attachments, data-form-web-part

As most of you probably know, once you customize a form and use **DataFormWebPart** you lose the attachments functionality.

After spending several hours investigating this subject, I've installed [Hotfix 953749](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/953271) and successfully managed to display the attached file in EditForm.aspx with DataFormWebPart.

However, I'm still having a problem displaying an AttachmentUpload field in NewForm.aspx (which should let my users the option to add an attachment when creating a new item)

I've tried the following tags in NewForm.aspx, yet the field is not visible.

```
<SharePoint:FieldLabel ControlMode="New" FieldName="Attachments" runat="server"/><br/>
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="AttachmentsField{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Attachments" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('AttachmentsField',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Attachments')}"/><br/>
```

And also:

```
  <SharePoint:AttachmentUpload ControlMode="new" runat="server" ID="fileupload{$Pos}"><br/>
  </SharePoint:AttachmentUpload><br/>
  <SharePoint:AttachmentsField  ControlMode="new" FieldName="Attachments" runat="server" Visible="true"><br/>
  </SharePoint:AttachmentsField>
```

Is there any other way doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered that you can upload files to Blog template with the following method:

1. Enable lists attachments in Advanced Settings
2. Create a custom field type that renders a FileUpload Control.
3. Add a field of this type to the Posts list. (List settings -> Add Column...)
4. When creating a new item, the option to select a file will be given.
5. Click on the Browse button and select a file.
6. Press OK to submit the form.

Voila! Check item's attachments you'll see that the file you selected before has been uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the hotfix 953749 of WSS3.0

on code of form change the tag xsl named dvt_1 for this

```
<xsl:template name="dvt_1">

    <xsl:variable name="dvt_StyleName">ListForm</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row"/>

    <div>

            <span id="part1">

            <table border="0" width="100%">

                            <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.body">

                                            <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>

                            </xsl:call-template>

            </table>

            </span>

            <SharePoint:AttachmentUpload runat="server" ControlMode="Edit"/>

            <SharePoint:ItemHiddenVersion runat="server" ControlMode="Edit"/>

            </div>

</xsl:template>
```

before the tag

```
<xsl:if test="$dvt_1_automode = '1'" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1" />
```

write the code:

```
<tr id="idAttachmentsRow">
 <td nowrap="true" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel" width="20%">
   <SharePoint:FieldLabel ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="Attachments" runat="server"/>
  </td>
<td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="80%">
 <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="AttachmentsField" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="Attachments" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u','AttachmentsField','Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Attachments')}"/>
                   <script>
var elm = document.getElementById("idAttachmentsTable");
if (elm == null || elm.rows.length == 0)
      document.getElementById("idAttachmentsRow").style.display='none';
                  </script> </td>
     </tr>
```

Note: On the ControlMode of code change the correct Mode for Insert or Update for New and Edit respectivily. For Bind Parameters "ddwrt:DataBind(''" replace 'u' for 'i' by the Insert Forms.

Have a nice Code... #/* :D *#

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this, but I have a lot of bad experience using Attachments. We typically find attachments a bad idea because the documents are not easily used by most people. They are hard to find and they can't be assigned any metadata. A better approach seems to be uploading the file to a separate document library and then adding a link to the file when necessary. This allows people to take advantage of the powerful document managment capabilities such as checkin/out, versioning, etc.

Comment: I think also that at least in WSS 3 that file attachments are not indexed and cannot be searched like they could if in a document library.